# Discord.py: Not sure where is the problem in my Kick Member command

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I have been working on my bot for a while and I had a fully functioning Kick command earlier. But I recently deleted that code permanently and now when I making another command I don't understand where the error is. It might be a silly thing that I have missed but trust me when typing a long code you forget some small things. :)

#### How do I know there is an error?

Whenever I execute this command nothing happens. The first two statements for **Administrator** and **Moderator** works fine but when it moves to the else statement, I don't know it just doesn't do anything. No one is kicked and no embed is sent.

Any help with it would be appreciated. Please find out the error in the command code below:

```
@nucleobot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True, kick_members=True, ban_members=True)
async def kick(ctx, member: discord.Member, *, reason=None):
    if member.guild_permissions.administrator:
        isadminembed=discord.Embed(title="Kick [!kick]", description=f"The member, {member.mention}, you are trying to kick is an server administrator. \n You can't kick them and thus, don't try again. :slight_smile:", color=discord.Colour.random())
        isadminembed.set_author(name="NucleoBot")
        isadminembed.set_thumbnail(url="https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/824634237008740402/832106457813090304/NucleoBot.png")
        await ctx.channel.send(embed=isadminembed)

    elif member.role.id in moderator_roles:
        ismodembed=discord.Embed(title="Kick [!tempkick]", description=f"The member, {member.mention}, you are trying to kick is an server moderator. \n You can't kick them and thus, don't try again. :slight_smile:", color=discord.Colour.random())
        ismodembed.set_author(name="NucleoBot")
        ismodembed.set_thumbnail(url="https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/824634237008740402/832106457813090304/NucleoBot.png")
        await ctx.channel.send(embed=ismodembed)
    
    else:
        if reason == None:
            kickedembed=discord.Embed(title="Kick [!tempkick]", description=f"The member, {member.mention}, has been succesfully kicked from the server. \n \nReason: Not Provided", color=discord.Colour.random())
            kickedembed.set_author(name="NucleoBot")
            kickedembed.set_thumbnail(url="https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/824634237008740402/832106457813090304/NucleoBot.png")
        else:
            kickedembed=discord.Embed(title="Kick [!tempkick]", description=f"The member, {member.mention}, has been succesfully kicked from the server. \n \nReason: {reason}", color=discord.Colour.random())
            kickedembed.set_author(name="NucleoBot")
            kickedembed.set_thumbnail(url="https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/824634237008740402/832106457813090304/NucleoBot.png")
        await nucleobot.kick(member)
        await ctx.channel.send(embed=kickedembed)
```

I have tried different solutions by making small changes but not sure where am I lacking. :(

Thank You! :)

Comment: Can you tell the error?

Comment: There is none. This is some logical error, I guess, as nothing comes up in the Terminal!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right this is a newbie logical error, think of what you are trying to do here, you have an `if` statement, an `elif` statement and an `else` statement. Python control flow is like this. It checks the if condition, if its true, it executes it and **doesn't check the elif condition or runs the else**, so it will directly end the function, or move on to the line after the else. Here is what you need to do:

```py
# if block to check their role (admin/mod)
if admin:
   #do stuff

elif moderator:
   #do stuff

else:
   # they are not a mod or an admin, handle case here

#another if block to check for reason 
if reason == None:
   #do stuff
else:
   # there is a valid reason

#kick member
await nucleobot.kick(member)
await ctx.channel.send(embed=kickedembed)
```

Answer (score -2):

To kick members, you have to use:

```
await Guild.kick(user, reason=reason)
```

or

```
await member.kick(reason=reason)
```

References:

[discord.Member.kick(*, reason=None)](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=kick#discord.Member.kick)

[discord.Guild.kick(user, *, reason=None)](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=kick#discord.Guild.kick)

Comment: Mate you didn't go through my code correctly! No Offence! The function use `discord.Member` as `member`. Plus I have tried the second one and it doesn't work.

Comment: I am sorry the only kick line I saw was await nucleobot.kick(member)
where you are using bot.kick(member) but not member.kick(reason=reason). Can you maybe point out what I am missing here?
Also I just saw an error in my code and corrected it, you could try again with the second one